# Time consuming in xml parsing in android

Tags: android, asynchronous, xml-parsing

i am using a map in my android app and display multiple item on map. all data coming from web services (XML). i am using SAX parser for that. and parsing in asynchronous task.

my problem is that data is too large and my loader show for about 1 minutes for parsing xml. 
so is there any way to resolve this problem.

i have one idea that when first item will parse than it will show on map and all remaining item will be loaded in thread. but how can i implement this?

is it possible?
need some suggestion and guidance.   thanks in advance.

Comment: how many number of line you are getting in response?

Comment: its about 100-200 items. and each item has 10 nodes.

Comment: I have used SAX where number of response line are 16000 and it takes maximum 1.5 minute

Are you testing on device or emulator ?

Comment: on real device and emulator both it take 2 minute. one thing more when user scroll map i am capture scroll stop event and again calling web service for that lat long.